# Enable to execute gcc when installing pyodbc on Cygwin

Tags: pip, cygwin, pyodbc

So I am using Cygwin on Windows and trying to install pyodbc but I have the following error. I have 2 questions:
1- How can I solve this error and install pyodbc
2- There is the possibility to install some packages on Cygwin at the time of installation. However I work in a company with high security and every time I need to install a package I would need to call the IT desk. Is there a way to avoid this when I want to `apt-get install` ?

```
$ pip3 install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-4.0.30.tar.gz (266 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyodbc
  Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-it4lbnab/pyodbc_7ecc5f1404444b59804b3bea7f531f2c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-it4lbnab/pyodbc_7ecc5f1404444b59804b3bea7f531f2c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-8kxd4enk
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-it4lbnab/pyodbc_7ecc5f1404444b59804b3bea7f531f2c/
  Complete output (10 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pyodbc' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.cygwin-3.2.0-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.cygwin-3.2.0-x86_64-3.6/src
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python36/python36-3.6.13-2.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python36-3.6.13-2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python36/python36-3.6.13-2.x86_64/src/Python-3.6.13=/usr/src/debug/python36-3.6.13-2 -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python36/python36-3.6.13-2.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python36-3.6.13-2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python36/python36-3.6.13-2.x86_64/src/Python-3.6.13=/usr/src/debug/python36-3.6.13-2 -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.cygwin-3.2.0-x86_64-3.6/src/buffer.o
  unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
  Running setup.py clean for pyodbc
Failed to build pyodbc
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
    Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-it4lbnab/pyodbc_7ecc5f1404444b59804b3bea7f531f2c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-it4lbnab/pyodbc_7ecc5f1404444b59804b3bea7f531f2c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1yowmoni/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.6m/pyodbc
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-it4lbnab/pyodbc_7ecc5f1404444b59804b3bea7f531f2c/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.cygwin-3.2.0-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.cygwin-3.2.0-x86_64-3.6/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python36/python36-3.6.13-2.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python36-3.6.13-2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python36/python36-3.6.13-2.x86_64/src/Python-3.6.13=/usr/src/debug/python36-3.6.13-2 -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python36/python36-3.6.13-2.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python36-3.6.13-2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/pub/devel/python/python36/python36-3.6.13-2.x86_64/src/Python-3.6.13=/usr/src/debug/python36-3.6.13-2 -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.cygwin-3.2.0-x86_64-3.6/src/buffer.o
    unable to execute 'gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-it4lbnab/pyodbc_7ecc5f1404444b59804b3bea7f531f2c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-it4lbnab/pyodbc_7ecc5f1404444b59804b3bea7f531f2c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1yowmoni/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python3.6m/pyodbc Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: have you installed the gcc compiler ? Why is you pip3 linked to Python 3.6 as the default is 3.8 ?

Comment: About installing, have you tried `setup-x86_64.exe -B` ? It will not elevated and will allow an installation for only your user

Comment: @matzeri thanks, I don't know why. I actually have Python 3.9 installed so I have to check why it is linked to 3.6.

Comment: @matzeri The command `setup-x86_64.exe -B` works so good. Is it possible to use this trick for any software installation? It would be magic. I moved from a company with low security to high security and this is a pain.

Comment: python3.9 is not from a Cygwin package. Last is 3.8.10. It seems you are mixing Windows and Cygwin versions of python

Comment: `setup-x86_64.exe -B` is Cygwin setup specific. Of course you can use as many time as you need.